# Dynamically change graph title upon selection plot_ly

Tags: r, plot, shiny

I have the following piece of code in my shiny server:

```
  output$SimilarityComparison <- renderPlotly({
    df <- newmpresults[place == input$CitySelected & upc_code == input$SKUSelected & category == input$categoryselectedtrends,]
    graph.title <- df$description
    plot_ly(
      #newmpresults[place == input$CitySelected & upc_code == input$SKUSelected & category == input$categoryselectedtrends,],
      df,
      x=~quantity,
      y = ~unit_price,
      text = ~paste("Precio: ", unit_price, '$<br>Cantidad:', quantity, '<br>MP:', type),
      color = ~as.factor(type)) %>%
      add_markers()%>%
      layout(
        title = ~paste('Producto:', graph.title),
        xaxis = list(title ='Cantidad'),
        yaxis = list(title ='Precio')) %>%
      config(displayModeBar = FALSE)
  })
```

and I would like that upon changing the selection in the UI, the title of my graph changes and gets displayed in the graph (only the `layout( title = ~paste('Producto:', graph.title)` part is giving me problems). I thought it was going to be as easy as just declaring `df$description` as my title input but it is not being displayed in the graph. Everything else works well. Any advice that you could give me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `df$description` is not a single entry, you have a vector as your title. Try this

```
graph.title <- unique(df$description)
layout( title = paste('Producto:', graph.title)
```

Comment: thanks man, I completely forgot that `df$description` was a vector.